# Entity Framework memory leak in Azure worker role

Tags: entity-framework, azure, memory-leaks, entity-framework-5

I investigate my `worker role` memory dumps using `WinDbg`.
I found the following results by grabbing dumps every half hour from `WaWorkerHost.exe` locally. First column is a count of objects, second is a size. Also, most expensive objects in the dump have `string` type.

- **35360**   3394560 System.Data.Objects.EntitySqlQueryState
- **40256**   3864576 System.Data.Objects.EntitySqlQueryState
- **45152**   4334592 System.Data.Objects.EntitySqlQueryState

I found that class here http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Core/Objects/Internal/EntitySqlQueryState.cs
And you can see that it caches query string.

Is it possible that `Entity Framework` caches that objects without any releases ?

I found an article that `NHibernate` can.
http://rasmuskl.dk/2008/12/19/a-windbg-debugging-journey-nhibernate-memory-leak/

That worker role automatically restart every day on production server when `RAM` is over.

I have `Entity Framework 5`, `Azure SDK 2.5`.
Please, help me with that issue, what could you advice ?

Comment: Are you disposing your DbContext at some point?

Comment: @raderick yes, i create each time a new one and use it within `using`

Comment: do you also have an option to update Entity Framework to latest? It's quite possible that old version has a leak

Comment: Its a big project - so it is not so easy to update all

Comment: I am afraid you don't have a lot of options here. Each version of entity framework has some bugs specific to it, version 5 is quite old and you don't have a lot of options here. I would try profiling memory and taking snapshots every now and then, and probably updating to latest EF6 stable version, which might magically fix a lot of possible issues.